# Find all $a,b,c\in\mathbb{Z}_{\neq0}$ with $\frac ab+\frac bc=\frac ca$

Tags: diophantine-equations, fractions, integers

As the title implies, I'm looking for triples $(a,b,c)$, where $a,b,c$ are nonzero integers, with $$\frac ab+\frac bc=\frac ca$$

---

I checked the cases $-100<a,b,c<100$ where $a,b,c\neq 0$ (using Wolfram Mathematica), and found no solutions. Because of this, I conjecture there'd be no solutions.

---

One idea was using AM-GM, but we barely limit out choice of $a,b,c$ with that. Another idea is to write $ca^2+ab^2=bc^2$ and solving this for, say, $a$ to get $$a=-\frac{b^2}{2c}\pm\frac{1}{2c}\sqrt{b^4+4bc^3}$$
so proving $b^4+4bc^3$ is never a square would be sufficient, but no luck with that either.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you were too quick to accept orangeskid's answer. Are you sure it's correct?

Comment: I read and understood his proof, and I'm pretty sure it doesn't contain any mistakes. Are you unsure of the correctness of his work?

Comment: Your comment to orangeskid's answer explains everything!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Write $x=a/b$,$y=b/c$, $z=c/a$ so get the system $x+y=z$ and $x y z=1$,
therefore $x y (x+y)=1$, with $x$, $y$,$z$ rationals. Now write $x=m/q$, $y=n/q$ and we get 
$$m/q \cdot n/q \cdot (m+n)/q = 1$$ or
$$m n (m+n) = q^3$$

We may assume that the numbers $m$, $n$, $m+n$ are pairwise relatively prime, otherwise get rid of the common factor. Therefore, $m$, $n$ and $m+n$ are all cubes, impossible ( Fermat for cubes, proved by Euler).

Comment: "get rid of the common factor": how does that work?

Comment: If a prime $p$ divides two of $n,m,n+m$, then surely it divides all three - thus, $p^3|mn(n+m)$ and so we may divide $m,n$ and $q$ by $p$ to retrieve the equation with the pairwise $\gcd$ equal to $1$.

Comment: @vrugtehagel: It's all the same to prove the equation has no rational solutions, hence by your method, it's equivalent to $b^4 + 4 b^3 c \ne d^2$, for $b$, $c \ne 0$. Divide by $c^4$ and get the equivalent statement that the curve $1 + 4 x^3 = y^2$ has no rational point except $(0,1)$. So we get ourselves another elliptic curve with no rational points beside some obvious one.